# Scheduled spesific time queries

Tags: php, cron

I have a table which is i showed on picture below.

[Flight Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jl1N3.png)

**MYSQL TABLE**

> [Id], [flightCode], [TailId], [DepartureFrom], [DepartureDate],
> [ArrivedTo], [ArrivalDate], [Status]

**VALUES**

> [*1], [TK161], [TC-AAS], [DLM], [04.03.2021 15:00], [IST], [04.03.2021
> 16:02], [2]

I want to run mysql query for update Status from "2" to "3" after reach to ArrivalDate in real system time.

Which method I should to use?

Comment: You need to be more specific - Rather ask how you should write the SQL or how you should synchronise to the system clock. etc. This is too broad to answer right now.

Answer (score 0):

What you really want is to have status be a computed column or query and compute that column on the fly. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html doing continuous updates across a database is VERY processor intensive and unnecessary.
so instead of `SELECT * FROM TABLE` you could do

```sql
SELECT *,
CASE WHEN NOW() >=  ArrivalDate THEN 3 ELSE 2 END AS `Status`
FROM TABLE
```

This query will give you the correct status at query time.  So the work to compute it only happens when it is needed.  I assume that there are other conditions for status but you can nest them into the case or have an outer case for those